# How to take picture with MvxPictureChooserTask from mvvmcross vnext?

Tags: xamarin.android, mvvmcross

I would like to take a picture from camera and after display it on the screen.
I saw this post [Take picture mvvmcross monodroid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13475896/need-an-example-of-take-a-picture-with-monodroid-and-mvvmcross) but this isn't the vnext version. (I haven't the Cirrious.MvvmCross.Interfaces.Platform.Tasks resource)

Can someone help me to implement this feature in my application ?

---

Using mvvmcross vNext and monodroid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The picture choosing (camera and library) interfaces moved into a Plugin for vNext, so you need to:

- reference Cirrious.MvvmCross.Plugins.PictureChooser in your ViewModel project
- reference Cirrious.MvvmCross.Plugins.PictureChooser.Droid in your Droid UI project
- make sure you call EnsureLoaded on the PictureChooser Plugin before you use it

Apart from that, the actual code should work the same as in Master (I think).

---

Other possibly helpful links are

- [uploading photo to a webservice with mvvmcross and mono touch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13958665/uploading-photo-to-a-webservice-with-mvvmcross-and-mono-touch)
- [Issues taking images and showing them with MvvmCross on WP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13725439/issues-taking-images-and-showing-them-with-mvvmcross-on-wp)
- [Need an example of take a Picture with MonoDroid and MVVMCross](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13475896/need-an-example-of-take-a-picture-with-monodroid-and-mvvmcross)
- https://github.com/Redth/WshLst/ - use Xam.Mobile instead

---

Would love to see a sample published on this :)

Comment: Thanks - Please be careful testing Android Activity lifecycles when taking big (* Megapixel) pictures - sometimes you have to hook into the SavedInstanceState code in order to preserve field values!

Comment: Comments are not for questions